# Downloading a file using R

Tags: r

How would I go about download a file using R?

**Link to the file**

http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20170301T07:00-0000&enddatetime=20170323T07:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&node=GONDER_LNODEN1&resultformat=6

**error message I get form my first try:**

```
trying URL 'http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20210301T07:00-0000&enddatetime=20210323T07:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&node=GONDER_LNODEN1&resultformat=6'
Error in download.file(zip_url, destfile = zip_path, mode = "wb", timeout = 120) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20210301T07:00-0000&enddatetime=20210323T07:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&node=GONDER_LNODEN1&resultformat=6'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(zip_url, destfile = zip_path, mode = "wb", timeout = 120) :
  URL 'http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20210301T07:00-0000&enddatetime=20210323T07:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&node=GONDER_LNODEN1&resultformat=6': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
```

**Error message from second try:**

```
Error in curl_download(zip_url, zip_path, timeout_ms = 120000, chunk_size = 1024 *  : 
  unused arguments (timeout_ms = 120000, chunk_size = 1024 * 1024)
```

**The code I tried:**

```
library(utils)
library(utils)

# Set the URL of the zip file to download
zip_url <- "http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=PRC_INTVL_LMP&startdatetime=20210301T07:00-0000&enddatetime=20210323T07:00-0000&version=3&market_run_id=RTM&node=GONDER_LNODEN1&resultformat=6"

# Set the location to save the downloaded zip file
zip_path <- "E:/Data - Test Download/my_data.zip"

# Download the zip file from the URL and save it to the specified location
download.file(zip_url, destfile = zip_path, mode = "wb", timeout = 120)

# second try:

library(curl)
curl_download(zip_url, zip_path, timeout_ms = 120000, chunk_size = 1024 * 1024)
```

Comment: (1) I don't think anything in "R" can work around "timeout" errors. (2) Where did you see options `timeout_ms` for `curl::curl_download`? The [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/curl.pdf) don't include those args for any of its functions (not just that func).

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the server timing out, rather than with R. Visiting that link in a browser generates an empty zip file.

Comment: `download.file(URL, "XML.zip")` Worked for me.

Comment: The server takes a long time when you just click on the link too. And this interface online takes forever to download anything.  Why I would like to do this over R. I tried this in python and it works. Just was using R and would have been nice to get it to work there as well.

Comment: Thank you r2evans I just found the curl code online. Which looks to be wrong. This works. curl_download(zip_url, zip_path)

Answer (score 0):

The answer thanks to @r2evans

```
curl::curl_download(zip_url, zip_path)
```